# Obtaining value of stored procedure OUT parameter using PHP PDO in a Transaction

Tags: php, pdo

I tried to retrieve the value of an ID after an insert. I'm using 2 stored procedures to accomplish this. For some reason, I can't get the value of the out parameter. I keep on getting an error message that reads

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'lkjlkjlkjlkj'
>   in 'field list'

This is the method I created.

```
function addTopicLesson(Topic $topic, Lesson $lesson)
{
    $isSuccessful = false;
    $this->connection->beginTransaction(); //start transaction
    try{
        $lessonNo = $lesson->getLessonNo();
        $lessonTitle = $lesson->getLessonTitle();
        $sp_addLesson = $this->connection->prepare( "CALL addLesson($lessonNo,$lessonTitle, @lessonId)");
        $sp_addLesson->execute();
        $sp_addLesson->closeCursor();

        $lessonId =$this->connection->query("select @lessonId")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //var_dump($lessonId);

        $topicId = $topic->getTopicId();
        $sp_addTopicLesson = $this->connection->prepare("CALL addTopicLesson($topicId,$lessonId)");
        $sp_addTopicLesson->execute();
        $this->connection->commit(); //commit
        $isSuccessful = true;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $this->connection->rollBack();
    }
    return $isSuccessful;
}
```

And my stored procedure,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addTopicLesson`(`pTopicId` INT, `pLessonId` INT)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO topic_lesson(topic_id, lesson_id)
VALUES(pTopicId,pLessonId);

END
```

And here's the "**addLesson**" stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addLesson`(`pLessonNo` INT, `pLessonTitle` VARCHAR(255), OUT opLessonId INT)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO lesson (lesson_no, lesson_title)
VALUES(pLessonNo,pLessonTitle);

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO opLessonId;

SELECT opLessonId AS opLessonId;

END
```

I'd appreciate any suggestion or correction.

Thank you.

Comment: In your call `CALL addLesson($lessonNo,$lessonTitle, @lessonId)`, you need quotes round the string values - perhaps `CALL addLesson($lessonNo,'$lessonTitle', @lessonId)` OR more ideally use a prepared statement with bind variables.

Comment: @NigelRen if I can `bindParam()` input param like this : `bindParam(1,lessonNo,PDO::PARAM_INT)` , how do I do it with `OUT` parameters in case of `@lessonId`?

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate posted above, it will show you how to get the value.